# Breadth First Search from scratch in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote a java-code to find the path in an 2d array. The array is filled with 0=valid node and 1=obstacle. The code runs perfetcly with small 2d arrays for example with the size of `int [][] obstacleMap=new int[10][11];`

When I increase the size of the array (e.g. `int[][] obstacleMap =[600][300];`) now the code doesn't work anymore, I get not an Error. I have tested a lot of times my code, I think the problem is the `while` loop within the `findpath` function (code below)

My code has following functions:

1. main: to test the other functions

2.findPath: find path with given map from start position to target position

3.addNeighbour: add neighbour

Following classes:

1. Node : x and y coordinates and distance to start
2. pathCoordinates: x and y values for path

The Code is here:

```
package strategyRobot;
//import java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class strategyRobotClass {
    static Set<String> visitedNodes = new HashSet<>();




public static void main(String[] args) {

           int[][] randomMap={
                    { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                    { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 },
                };
        
        int value = randomMap[2][6];
        System.out.printf("value = %d", value);
        System.out.println(" ");
 
    
        LinkedList<pathCoordinates> pathMap= findPath(randomMap,0,0,3,6);
        for(int i = 0; i<pathMap.size();i++) {
            System.out.printf("(%d,%d) %n",pathMap.get(i).x,pathMap.get(i).y);
            
        }
            
    }

    static public LinkedList<pathCoordinates> findPath(int map[][], int xStartPos, int yStartPos, int xTargetPos, int yTargetPos) {
        LinkedList<pathCoordinates> pathMap = new LinkedList<pathCoordinates>();
        Node source = new Node(xStartPos, yStartPos,0);
        Queue<Node> queue= new LinkedList<Node>();
        queue.add(source);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) { // IS THE BUG HERE ????
            Node poped = queue.poll();
            if(poped.x == xTargetPos && poped.y ==yTargetPos) {
                return pathMap;
            }
            else {
                map[poped.x][poped.y] = 1 ;
                pathCoordinates coordinates = new pathCoordinates(poped.x,poped.y);
                pathMap.add(coordinates);
                List<Node> neighbourList = addNeighbours(poped,map);
                queue.addAll(neighbourList);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



static public List addNeighbours(Node poped, int[][] map) {

        List<Node> list=new LinkedList<Node>();
        if((poped.x-1 >0 && poped.x-1<map.length) && (map[poped.x-1][poped.y]== 0)) {
            list.add(new Node(poped.x-1, poped.y, poped.distanceFromStart+1));
        }
        if((poped.x+1 >0 && poped.x+1<map.length) && (map[poped.x+1][poped.y]== 0)) {
            list.add(new Node(poped.x+1, poped.y, poped.distanceFromStart+1));
        }
        
        if((poped.y-1 >0 && poped.y-1<map.length) && (map[poped.x][poped.y-1]== 0)) {
            list.add(new Node(poped.x-1, poped.y, poped.distanceFromStart+1));
        }
        
        if((poped.y+1 >0 && poped.y+1<map.length) && (map[poped.x][poped.y+1]== 0)) {
            list.add(new Node(poped.x, poped.y+1, poped.distanceFromStart+1));
        }
        return list;
        
    }
 static public class Node{
    int x, y; //coordinates in a cell
    int distanceFromStart;
    Node parent;
    Node(int x, int y, int distanceFromStart){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.distanceFromStart=distanceFromStart;
    }
}

static public class pathCoordinates {
    int x,y;
    pathCoordinates(int x, int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have declared `visitedNodes` but you never populate it, which makes the algorithm re-visit the nodes it has already visited making the performance much worse. The code you have would eventually work but it can be easily optimized by not revisiting the same nodes.

Comment: In `addNeighbor`, shouldn't the `x-1 > 0` and `y-1 > 0`  really be `x-1 >= 0`/`y-1 >= 0`?  A cell at (1, y) or (x, 1)  has a neighbor at (0, y) or (x, 0), yes?

Comment: thank you! it helped I think this is the solution. I have to test the code

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you! you are right